# I want to change the color of the required field symbol (asterisk) to red

Tags: asp.net-core, validation, required, mudblazor

I want to change the color of the required field symbol (asterisk) to red.I'am using Mud-Blazor. I tried it using the below code.  [this is the image after i apply the code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KXvpm.png)  This is the code i'm using for asterisk to show in red color.

```
<style>
 .mud-input-required::before {
  content: "*";
  color: red;
  margin-right: 2px;
    }

  .mud-label {
   display: flex;
   align-items: center;
    }
</style>
```

Comment: Please update the first question you posted. [I have two required fields in my form .I want the asterisk color should be red.Currently it is showing black](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77745665/i-have-two-required-fields-in-my-form-i-want-the-asterisk-color-should-be-red-c)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<MudTextField @bind-Value="HelperText" Class="red-asterisk-required" Label="With Helper" Variant="Variant.Outlined" />
<br>
<MudTextField @bind-Value="HelperText" Label="With Helper" Variant="Variant.Outlined" />

<style>
.red-asterisk-required .mud-input-label::after {
    content: " *";
    color: red;
}
</style>

@code {
    public string HelperText { get; set; }
}
```

refer this Link https://try.mudblazor.com/snippet/wOQIEbEdfXffXybS

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**